# Can I run deeplab completely on CPU?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, cpu, semantic-segmentation, deeplab

Can I run the DeepLab image segmentation completely on CPU?

I have access to hpc, with high Memory resources but it is not GPU-enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can run it completely on the CPU. For that you only have to make a small change:

Open the file train.py and include the line

`os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]=""`

before tensorflow is included.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I got access to a GPU enabled cluster, though. It works much faster now. I cannot set batch size more than 12, but it's still fast

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. In fact you might not need to change the code at all to run it on a CPU-only machine.